# Current diagnostic interviews for DSM-V

Tags: measurement, clinical-psychology

I was wondering if there are currently any diagnostic interview schedules that have been made/adapted to fit DSM-V criteria? Have you heard of anything?

Specifically, I am looking for interviews for children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [SCID  is a Structured Clinical Interview for DSM Disorders](http://www.scid4.org/).

The SCID website talks about a version designed for children called the [KID-SCID](http://www.scid4.org/info/kidscid.html).

You mention a specific interest in DSM-V. Under "what's new", the SCID website states:

> January 2013: Development efforts are underway for the SCID for DSM-5
>   and updated training materials, which are expected to be released in
>   the fall/winter 2013.